# JButton ActionListener not responding

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I couldn't find the answer anywhere else online, so I came here. I apologize in advance if the mistake in my code is very obvious; I'm still quite new to java swing. Here's what's going on: I have created a JButton named `toggleElevators`, and I want it to change text when clicked. I have already created an ActionListener and added it to `toggleElevators`. All I want right now is for the JButton to change text when clicked from `Click me` to `Clicked`.

First, here's a picture of what the JFrame looks like when executed:

[image: JFrame]

NOTE: There is a third class, but it is **purely** for drawing the picture on the left. It has nothing to do with the GridLayout or the JButton.

`Run` class (created frame and adds `toggleElevators` JButton:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Run extends Input{

Input i = new Input();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Run();
}

public Run() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Elevators");
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new Elevators(Color.MAGENTA, true));
            frame.add(new Elevators(Color.ORANGE, false));
            frame.setSize(800,600);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            frame.getContentPane().add(toggleElevators); //adds toggleElevators button to JFrame
            i.addButtonListeners(); //calls method defined in Input class, which adds the ActionListener to the toggleElevators button

            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}
```

`Input` class (creates `toggleElevators` JButton and its ActionListener):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Input {
JButton toggleElevators = new JButton("Click me.");

public void addButtonListeners() {
    toggleElevators.addActionListener(new toggleElevatorsListener());
}

class toggleElevatorsListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        toggleElevators.setText("Clicked.");
        System.out.println("ActionListener called."); //I know the ActionListener is not being called because this line is not being printed out in the console
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you complicating things? Why don't you add a `ActionListener` to the `JButton` directly?

Comment: @NabeelOmer Is that what is causing the problem? Created an inner class for the ActionListener? I didn't think that would do anything.

Comment: I am not near a computer right now (hell, it's 4 in the morning here), but you are complicating things by making a separate class for the `ActionListener` try adding it to the `JButton` directly. And the

Comment: I think that's why anonymous class or lambda functions are for ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Run class extends Input, but also HAS an Input named `i`. You're adding `this.toggleElevators` to the frame, but you're adding a listener to `i.toggleElevators`.

Remove the `i` field from your class. I would also forget completely about defining and extending an Input class. It doesn't serve any purpose, and seems to confuse more than help you.

Comment: Thank you. I had completely forgotten that my code referred to basically separate instances of the `toggleElevators` button. I've followed your advice and deleted the `i` object, and that worked. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You create a new `Input` in your `Run` class, while the `Run` class also extends `Input`.

When you call `i.addButtonListeners();` the action listeners are added on the `toggleElevators` from `i` and not on the `toggleElevators` you inherited from the `Input` class.

Try `addButtonListeners()`.

Comment: Just figured that out on my own. Thanks anyways for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Run` class extends `Input`. Therefore it has its own `toggleElevators` which is the one it sets in the frame. However, `i` has is own `toggleElevators` where it sets the event listeners. So they are not set on the one in the frame but on one that never gets used.

You can simply delete the `i` object. As `Run` extends `Input`, it can call the method directly, and then the listener will be added to its own `toggleElevators`.